# Create an Image link right next to the content title of a content type

Tags: nodes, media

How do I create an image(eg. plus_sign.png) link just next to the content title of a given content type? Please help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to do some database operation on click of the image link through ajax. I need the link right next to the title. Please advice!

Comment: If your going to use ajax anyway, you should probably just add the links dynamically.

Comment: Please elaborate a little more... I am new here

Comment: Use JS/jQuery to add the image/link next to the title dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out. Btw what I am trying to achieve is something that I posted earlier http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115987/add-taxonomy-terms-associated-to-a-content-with-the-user-profile-field-on-click . please help!